# What is the role of Crypt Key in env.php Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

What is the role of crypt in env.php in magento 2. The file is located at **app/etc/env.php**

Answer (score 3):

During the installation process, Magento 2 will generate a random encryption key, stored in `app/etc/env.php`. It is used to protect passwords and other sensitive data, using [hash & salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) method.

For a better understanding, you can take a look in `vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php` class which implements  `EncryptorInterface`.

Where is used ? For example in module-customer, module-sales, module-paypal (you can search by `EncryptorInterface` in `vendor/magento` to find all the modules that are using it.)

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-php.html

**Look for "Encryption key" on the page**

And you might want to look at this:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/trouble/trouble-crypt-key-variable.html

Apparently the crypt key is Magento generated and used in cloud environments.